# IdentityServer4 - How to log in user following password reset if existing auth cookie exists?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm attempting to extend my Identity Server 4 implementation and provide an in house password reset feature. I've completed the entire password reset process however I'm running into a situation upon redirecting the user back to the client application that's causing me grief.

If there is a valid existing authentication cookie, for instance if a previous user doesn't initiate a proper log out, when I redirect the current user to the client application, the middle ware uses the existing cookie to build the principal which inevitable ends up with the current user being treated as the previous user, which makes sense.

In vain I attempted to make a call to sign in the current user post password reset in Identity Server via `await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(...)`  as shown during login on their samples [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/dev/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs) with no change in results.

It seems as I'm missing something fundamental in how to properly reproduce the sign in process from within my password reset process.

Is there any way from Identity Server that I can effectively sign in the current user post password reset and force the client application to invalidate/ignore the existing authentication cookie?

**Update:** After thinking about this over the weekend, I guess this broaches a much broader subject in that how far does one go in ensuring the invalidation of existing auth cookies? The fact is that because of the way cookie authentication works, as long as that cookie remains valid we are under the assumption that we are is still receiving requests from the original physical person.

One might argue that this is a good case for reducing the expiration time of the cookie, but that's a slippery slope because on one hand if the expiration is too short, usability can be affected making for a less enjoyable experience and unhappy users. Make the expiration too long and that window where a valid auth cookie is sitting on the browser idle with no meat and bones behind it grows, and all it takes is someone else to browse to the site to proceed unhindered and authenticated as someone else. This would be most evident in a situation with shared computers where many people need to access the same app.

I suppose a secondary question would be to what extent is the onus on the user to initiate a proper logout process, and to what lengths should I go to to ensure any existing auth cookies are invalidated?

Answer (score 0):

After a few conversations with co workers, the consensus was that it is the responsibility of the user to ensure they are properly logged out in any public/computer sharing situations and that we could not guarantee without a reasonable doubt any previously existing authentication cookies are cleaned up without greatly affecting user experience and basic site functionality.

For due diligence we however will provide some manner of attempting to clean up any existing authentication cookies by doing a simple check and redirect on the default route of the client application. This solution has nothing to do with identity server, and is not fool proof, but in conjunction with tuning the session expiration times should prove effective for daily users.

```
    [AllowAnonymous, Route("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(...);
            HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Welcome));
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Welcome()
    {
        return View();
    }
```